# Доступ на сайт

Tags: сеть, http

Что нужно делать, чтоб в мой сайт можно было зайти через другой комп. в лок. сети?

Answer (score 2):

В локальной - ничего, только входить на него надо по сетевому IP. Плюс в httpd.conf должно быть `Listen 80` (а не `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`, например). Чтобы можно было входить по доменному имени, на сетевом DNS-сервере должна быть запись о вас.

Comment: спасибо, но по вашему не получается.
так как у меня сайт на денвере, попробовал по схеме приведенной здесь - http://www.denwer.ru/faq/shared.html (с помощью /.htaccess, т.е. создал такую файл в папке моего сайта) 
получилось с вводом IP адреса и только для одного сайта
я хочу чтобы входить с именем папки(т.е. сайта), и еще как я могу входить в другие сайты на сервере через другой комп
заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Установите веб-комплекс [VertrigoServ](http://vertrigo.sourceforge.net/?lang=ru) и не придется копать конфиги
2. Перенесите файлы своего сайта и БД на Vertrigo
3. Перезапустите Vertrigo
4. Теперь на ваш локальный сайт можно попасть, зная IP вашей машины, т.е. в браузере `http://в.а.ш.IP/`

Answer (score 0):

Знать IP веб-сервера в сети, на котором работает сайт, в файле hosts прописать следующее :

site_name.zone 000.000.000.000

site_name.zone - доменное имя сайта(ставится у веб-сервера в настройках хоста)

000.000.000.000- Ip адрес машины, на которой работает веб-сервер в сети(ставится у веб-сервера в настройках хоста)